# How can I queue multiple accessibility notifications for VoiceOver?

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

This is how I'm notifying the system to read out my elements:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, cell)
```

The problem is that when I send multiple notifications, the one that is already reading gets interrupted! I want to be able to queue it...

I also found in another question here that I should use attributed string:

```
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey(
    rawValue: UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributeQueueAnnouncement), 
    value: true, 
    range: range!.nsRange)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

I have made many tests to try and understand this behaviour that drove me crazy.

My conclusion is that if you send a notification while VoiceOver is speaking a {label / hint / value}, your notification won't be taken into account : there may be a kind of preemption when the system needs to vocalize an attribute of a focused element.

That's only at the end of the vocalization that you can post as many notifications as you want to be well analyzed and interpreted as you wish.

The `UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributeQueueAnnouncement` key is only useful with your own notifications when the system doesn't need to take over.

If you send many notifications and that the user flicks to focus a new element for instance, the notifications that weren't vocalized will be removed as soon as the system vocalizes the element's attributes.

In that case, if you catch the `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementDidFinish` event, you will have a false value with the `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementKeyWasSuccessful` key for the last vocalized notification (`UIAccessibilityAnnouncementKeyStringValue`)... all the following ones will be ignored with no info given by the observer.

Conclusion : **no personal notification is taken into account by VoiceOver when a new focused element or screen/layout changed notification occurs**.

> How can I queue multiple accessibility notifications for VoiceOver?

According to what's exposed above, I suggest to **set up a kind of retry mechanism** that would still send your notifications *(x times)* while they're not perfectly received after y seconds for instance.
That could be a tricky way to be more certain that the notifications are flawlessly received.

⚠️ **EDIT 2023/12/15** ⚠️

There are [new priorities](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/nota11y/2023/2310036/#priority) introduced in **iOS 17** that might be of interest regarding this topic. 
[image]

Answer (score 10):

With Swift 5 this is working for me:

```
if (UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning) {
     let message: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "read me", attributes: [.accessibilitySpeechQueueAnnouncement: true])
     UIAccessibility.post(notification: .announcement, argument: message)
}
```

The key is to set .accessibilitySpeechQueueAnnouncement true.

Answer (score 1):

`UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification` is supposed to be used when the app needs to make an ad-hoc announcement to the user. It's probably not designed to be called repeatedly.

If you did want to queue, you might need to post the first notification, then wait for `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementDidFinishNotification` to be posted by the system, then you could post the next message in your queue.

(But I'd offer caution: is this really what a visually-impaired user will be expecting?)

Comment: I tried listening on UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification but it never gets called when I post a notification for announcement...

Comment: The reason we need to make the announcement is because this is for a chat session (when the other party responds, we need to notify it as an announcement)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using https://github.com/spanage/AccessibilityAnnouncer for your own notifications but keep in mind that if the user taps and interacts with the screen these notifications will be ignored.